# How to redirect root domain to subdomain with https

Tags: dns, redirect

My setup are, 
- @ redicrect to `www.example.com`
- `www.example.com` CNAME to openshift account.
- https redirection is handled in the code.

Working:
`example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`
`www.example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`

Not Working
`https://example.com` -> "This site can’t be reached"
- I expect to redirect this to `https://www.example.com`

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: DNS does not care about https or http, it just resolves hostnames. How dd you set up `example.com -> https://www.example.com`?

Comment: I have redirected my root domain to my subdomain www then points www to my openshift hosting using CNAME.

actual url is bonaevents.com if you want to check.

https://bonaevents.com is not working.

Comment: OK, the `root domain to my subdomain www` part, you did that in namecheap console, as described [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/77/how-do-i-setup-url-forwarding-for-a-domain)?

Comment: yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your requirement is that DNS does not actually know anything about the protocol/scheme (either `http://` or `https://`), it only handles the hostname resolution. The part where you redirect from `example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, although configured in namecheap DNS console, actually involves a kind of a web server which (when you make a request for http://example.com) responds with `301 Redirect` to `https://www.example.com` - that is a service that DNS providers sometimes transparently offer to make life easier for their customer.

I am not familiar with namecheap offering, but I doubt that it is possible to configure`https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, since that would also have to involve that you somehow upload your SSL certs, but perhaps you can check with their support.

The other soultion might be that in namecheap console, instead of `example.com` -> `https://www.example.com` you configure `example.com` CNAME to openshift account. Then, in openshift you just make sure that your site responds to `example.com` also, and handle the `http -> https` redirection in code.

Comment: thank you for the response, yep I think you're correct.

However, at the last part, it is prohibited to use CNAME in the root domain.

Comment: True, I forgot about that.